# Prompting a transaction to metamask?

Tags: web3js, metamask

How do I prompt a transaction to MetaMask using web3/truffle? Like if I want a charge a user x amount of ether, and have them confirm the transaction via MetaMask.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you've set the right provider (i.e. `web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider)` to use MetaMask's injected provider), and then just make the transaction: `web3.eth.sendTransaction(...)`.

Comment: On my local net, there was no authorization used.

Answer (score 0):

Look out for this update.

```
window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
// Modern dapp browsers...
if (window.ethereum) {
    window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
    try {
        // Request account access if needed
        await ethereum.enable();
        // Acccounts now exposed
        web3.eth.sendTransaction({/* ... */});
    } catch (error) {
        // User denied account access...
    }
}
// Legacy dapp browsers...
else if (window.web3) {
    window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    // Acccounts always exposed
    web3.eth.sendTransaction({/* ... */});
}
// Non-dapp browsers...
else {
    console.log('Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider trying MetaMask!');
}
});
```

See this article for more on this update:
https://medium.com/metamask/https-medium-com-metamask-breaking-change-injecting-web3-7722797916a8